# JQuery loop through classes for attribute value, then change the display style depending on the attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a jQuery loop that checks all the classes `testfieldvalue` for what the `attribute value` they have, then shows a number of input fields that is matching the value.

The jQuery loop picks up both values `1,2` but it displays 2 input fields at the first `thefieldvalue` class, not one at the first `thefieldvalue` and two at the second `thefieldvalue` as it should. What am i doing wrong?

Please look at working example: https://jsfiddle.net/m9xr870f/

```js
var testfieldvalue = document.getElementsByClassName("testfieldvalue")[0].value;
var testfieldshow = document.getElementsByClassName("testfieldshow")[0];
var field1 = document.getElementsByClassName("Field_1")[0];
var field1label = document.getElementsByClassName("Field_1_label")[0];
var field2 = document.getElementsByClassName("Field_2")[0];
var field2label = document.getElementsByClassName("Field_2_label")[0];


$(".testfieldvalue[value]").each(function(){
 var testfield = ($(this).attr('value'));
 if (testfield == '1') {
  testfieldshow.style.display = '';
  field1.style.display = '';
  field1label.style.display = '';
 } else if (testfield == '2') {
  testfieldshow.style.display = '';
  field1.style.display = '';
  field1label.style.display = '';
  field2.style.display = '';
  field2label.style.display = '';
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input 1
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="testfieldvalue">
<div class="testfieldshow" name="testfieldshow" style="display: none">
 <label class="Field_1_label" style="display: none">Field 1</label>
 <input type="text" class="Field_1" name ="Field_1" style="display: none">
 <label class="Field_2_label" style="display: none">Field 2</label>
 <input type="text" class="Field_2" name ="Field_2" style="display: none">
</div>
<br>
Input 2
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="testfieldvalue">
<div class="testfieldshow" name="testfieldshow" style="display: none">
 <label class="Field_1_label" style="display: none">Field 1</label>
 <input type="text" class="Field_1" name ="Field_1" style="display: none">
 <label class="Field_2_label" style="display: none">Field 2</label>
 <input type="text" class="Field_2" name ="Field_2" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Comment: You can create a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow with [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), which will make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining variables above your loop you want to find the `Field_1`, `Field_2` and their labels in relation to `$(this)` inside the loop.

One way to do that is by using the jquery function `next()` with the appropriate selector - in this case `next('.testfieldshow')`

```js
$(".testfieldvalue[value]").each(function(){
 var testfield = ($(this).attr('value'));
 var fieldShow = $(this).next('.testfieldshow');
 var field1 = fieldShow.find('.Field_1')[0];
 var field1label = fieldShow.find('.Field_1_label')[0];
 var field2 = fieldShow.find('.Field_2')[0];
 var field2label = fieldShow.find('.Field_2_label')[0]; 
 
 if (testfield == '1') {
  fieldShow[0].style.display = '';
  field1.style.display = '';  
  field1label.style.display = '';
 } else if (testfield == '2') {
  fieldShow[0].style.display = '';
  field1.style.display = '';
  field1label.style.display = '';
  field2.style.display = '';
  field2label.style.display = '';
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input 1
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="testfieldvalue">
<div class="testfieldshow" name="testfieldshow" style="display: none">
 <label class="Field_1_label" style="display: none">Field 1</label>
 <input type="text" class="Field_1" name ="Field_1" style="display: none">
 <label class="Field_2_label" style="display: none">Field 2</label>
 <input type="text" class="Field_2" name ="Field_2" style="display: none">
</div>
<br>
Input 2
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="testfieldvalue">
<div class="testfieldshow" name="testfieldshow" style="display: none">
 <label class="Field_1_label" style="display: none">Field 1</label>
 <input type="text" class="Field_1" name ="Field_1" style="display: none">
 <label class="Field_2_label" style="display: none">Field 2</label>
 <input type="text" class="Field_2" name ="Field_2" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Comment: That makes so much more sense to find the values in relation to $(this). I got alot of learning to do now, thank you for the explanation, makes it so much easier to understand! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are making the labels and input visible by doing

```
testfieldshow.style.display = '';
field1.style.display = '';
...
```

but the variables `testfieldshow`, `field1` ... are initialized as

```
var testfieldshow = document.getElementsByClassName("testfieldshow")[0];
```

That `[0]` at the end makes the selector `document.getElementsByClassName("testfieldshow")` always pick the first found in the document, therefore the first div with class `testfieldshow`

So you are applying the `display = ''` on the same elements twice